# IBVP: Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

everyone!

Could someone help me out with a question?
There is a PDE, which is the heat equation. There is also a solution. In the solution, it says that an odd extension of the PDE has to be computed. Then it says, that to get a solution we need to multiply the $n$-th term by $e^{-\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2\alpha^2t}$.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why an odd extension is used and not an even one?
2. Why do we simply multiply by $e^{-\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2\alpha^2t}$ to get a solution?

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because $u(0,t)=0$, which does not hold for even functions $c_n\cos(nx)$ when $c_n\neq0$.
2. That is part of solving the PDE by separation of variables: you multiply every $n$-th $x$-function with its corresponding $t$-function and can sum them all together by the principle of superposition.

Comment: So, as I understand it, if we did an even extension then u(0,t) = 1? However, if we do an odd extension, isn't the function undefined due to a discontinuous jump from 1 to -1? Also, if we do an odd extension, are all the cn terms 0?

Comment: @euler132 For an even extension you would get that $c_n=0$, because $\cos(0)=1$, so it becomes trivial. In the second line, they should do $t>0$, else the function is not well-defined. It will indeed be discontinuous in $t=0$, but that is no problem. In the odd extension the terms are non-zero. As I can see, they have already been calculated in Assignment 4.

Comment: Well, I have just solved Assignment 4, and there has been no mention of it. The reason for that is that some of the questions are recycled from the previous years, but that doesn't matter. Anyways, thank you very much for your time! With your help, I have now understood about odd and even extensions.

Comment: P.S. I am new to math.stackexchange. Could you tell me what the best way is to type equations here when posting or answering a question? Thanks!

Comment: @euler132 No problem! Here is a link to using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

1. The wording of the solution is misleading because it implies you can tell whether an odd or even extension can be used just by looking at the initial conditions. In fact, there is no way to tell whether an odd or even extension would be used just by looking at the initial condition (the time condition). Just by changing the boundary conditions, this problem might as well give you an even extension.

   The solution said odd extension because it had already done the calculations for this particular problem in Assignment 4 and found that the solution in space involves only sine functions.
2. The exponential equation is the equation **in $t$ only**. This pde problem has been solved by the method separation of variables. If you look at the trigonometric term, it is a function **of $x$ only**. However, the original function is of **both $x$ and $t$**, which should make sense to you why we multiply the two functions together. To understand more about this method, you'd need to review what you went over in your class.

Comment: 1. This is a very good point! Thanks!